# Laravel - laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying to get this package to work: https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer

I did everything according to the description, but I get no output of the variables.

Laravel Version: laravel/framework (v5.2.24)

My config/app

```
Laracasts\Utilities\JavaScript\JavaScriptServiceProvider::class,
'JavaScript' => Laracasts\Utilities\JavaScript\JavaScriptFacade::class,
```

My config/javascript

```
'bind_js_vars_to_this_view' => 'footer',
'js_namespace' => 'qwerTEST'
```

in my controller

```
use JavaScript;
JavaScript::put(['fett' => 'testtesttest']);
```

in my main view

```
@include('layouts.footer');
```

my footer.blade.php

```
`<div>some text</div>`
```

and in my view

```
@extends('layouts.intern')

@section('content')
    <script>
        console.log('test');
        console.log(qwerTEST.fett);
    </script>
@endsection
```

the javascript of chrome gives out

```
test
Uncaught ReferenceError: qwerTEST is not defined
```

And there is nothing with qwerTEST javascript namespace in the sourcecode. But I get no error at all.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it:
in my config/javascript I have to write the full path to the view:

```
'bind_js_vars_to_this_view' => 'folder.footer'
```

Could be better described in the Package..